# AMPScript - FormatCurrency displaying symbols or ? in Emails

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have added:Set @Amount = Formatcurrency(Amount, "en-GB") This seems to be working for most ESP however in some I can see a '??' or  '��' Has anyone been able to get this resolved so that it only shows the currency symbol?

Comment: What's the encoding/charset in your email's HTML? What about in the properties of the email definition in SFMC?

Comment: the HTML charset is UTF-8 . How i do find the email definition properties?